# What is a C# analog of C++ std::pair?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, std-pair, base-class-library

What is a C#'s analog of `std::pair` in C++? I found `System.Web.UI.Pair` class, but I'd prefer something template-based.

Comment: I had the same request a while ago, but the more I thought about it, you may want to just roll your own pairing class, with explicit class types and fields instead of the generic "First" and "Second". It makes your code more readable. A pairing class can be as little as 4 lines, so you aren't saving much by reusing a generic Pair<T,U> class and your code will be more readable.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Tuples [are available since .NET4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) and support generics:

```
Tuple<string, int> t = new Tuple<string, int>("Hello", 4);
```

---

In previous versions you can use `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<K, V>` or a solution like the following:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    public Pair() {
    }

    public Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public T First { get; set; }
    public U Second { get; set; }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
Pair<String, int> pair = new Pair<String, int>("test", 2);
Console.WriteLine(pair.First);
Console.WriteLine(pair.Second);
```

This outputs:

```
test
2
```

Or even this chained pairs:

```
Pair<Pair<String, int>, bool> pair = new Pair<Pair<String, int>, bool>();
pair.First = new Pair<String, int>();
pair.First.First = "test";
pair.First.Second = 12;
pair.Second = true;

Console.WriteLine(pair.First.First);
Console.WriteLine(pair.First.Second);
Console.WriteLine(pair.Second);
```

That outputs:

```
test
12
true
```

Comment: See my post about adding a Equals method

Comment: Tuple<> is now a better solution.

Comment: Since type parameters belonging to the generic class cannot be inferred in an object creation expression (constructor call), the authors of BCL made a non-generic helper class called `Tuple`. Therefore you can say `Tuple.Create("Hello", 4)` which is a bit easier than `new Tuple<string, int>("Hello", 4)`. (By the way, .NET4.0 is already here since 2010.)

Comment: Mind you `Tuple<>` implements solid `Equals` and `GetHashCode` with value semantics which is great. Keep in mind when implementing your own tuples.

Comment: This is obviously broken because of Equals and GetHashCode

Comment: Not [Struct], but [Class]? I don't think it works same as [std::pair] in case of using [Pair] as C# dictionary key

Answer (score 98):

`System.Web.UI` contained the `Pair` class because it was used heavily in ASP.NET 1.1 as an internal ViewState structure.

**Update Aug 2017:** C# 7.0 / .NET Framework 4.7 provides a syntax to declare a Tuple with named items using the [`System.ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple.aspx) struct.

```
//explicit Item typing
(string Message, int SomeNumber) t = ("Hello", 4);
//or using implicit typing 
var t = (Message:"Hello", SomeNumber:4);

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", t.Message, t.SomeNumber);
```

see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx) for more syntax examples.

**Update Jun 2012:** [`Tuples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) have been a part of .NET since version 4.0.

Here is [an earlier article describing inclusion in.NET4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx) and support for generics:

```
Tuple<string, int> t = new Tuple<string, int>("Hello", 4);
```

Comment: Note that Tuples are read-only.  That is, you can't do this: `tuple.Item1 = 4;`

Answer (score 39):

Unfortunately, there is none. You can use the `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<K, V>` in many situations.

Alternatively, you can use anonymous types to handle tuples, at least locally:

```
var x = new { First = "x", Second = 42 };
```

The last alternative is to create an own class.

Comment: Just to be clear, anonymous types are also read-only - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

C# has [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as of version 4.0.

Answer (score 10):

Some answers seem just wrong,

1. you can't use dictionary how would store the pairs (a,b) and (a,c). Pairs concept should not be confused with associative look up of key and values
2. lot of the above code seems suspect

Here is my pair class

```
public class Pair<X, Y>
{
    private X _x;
    private Y _y;

    public Pair(X first, Y second)
    {
        _x = first;
        _y = second;
    }

    public X first { get { return _x; } }

    public Y second { get { return _y; } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        Pair<X, Y> other = obj as Pair<X, Y>;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return
            (((first == null) && (other.first == null))
                || ((first != null) && first.Equals(other.first)))
              &&
            (((second == null) && (other.second == null))
                || ((second != null) && second.Equals(other.second)));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashcode = 0;
        if (first != null)
            hashcode += first.GetHashCode();
        if (second != null)
            hashcode += second.GetHashCode();

        return hashcode;
    }
}
```

Here is some test code:

```
[TestClass]
public class PairTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void pairTest()
    {
        string s = "abc";
        Pair<int, string> foo = new Pair<int, string>(10, s);
        Pair<int, string> bar = new Pair<int, string>(10, s);
        Pair<int, string> qux = new Pair<int, string>(20, s);
        Pair<int, int> aaa = new Pair<int, int>(10, 20);

        Assert.IsTrue(10 == foo.first);
        Assert.AreEqual(s, foo.second);
        Assert.AreEqual(foo, bar);
        Assert.IsTrue(foo.GetHashCode() == bar.GetHashCode());
        Assert.IsFalse(foo.Equals(qux));
        Assert.IsFalse(foo.Equals(null));
        Assert.IsFalse(foo.Equals(aaa));

        Pair<string, string> s1 = new Pair<string, string>("a", "b");
        Pair<string, string> s2 = new Pair<string, string>(null, "b");
        Pair<string, string> s3 = new Pair<string, string>("a", null);
        Pair<string, string> s4 = new Pair<string, string>(null, null);
        Assert.IsFalse(s1.Equals(s2));
        Assert.IsFalse(s1.Equals(s3));
        Assert.IsFalse(s1.Equals(s4));
        Assert.IsFalse(s2.Equals(s1));
        Assert.IsFalse(s3.Equals(s1));
        Assert.IsFalse(s2.Equals(s3));
        Assert.IsFalse(s4.Equals(s1));
        Assert.IsFalse(s1.Equals(s4));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't implement IEquatable you will get boxing. There is more work to be done to complete your class correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from custom class or .Net 4.0 Tuples, since C# 7.0 there is a new feature called ValueTuple, which is a struct that can be used in this case. Instead of writing:

```
Tuple<string, int> t = new Tuple<string, int>("Hello", 4);
```

and access values through `t.Item1` and `t.Item2`, you can simply do it like that:

```
(string message, int count) = ("Hello", 4);
```

or even:

```
(var message, var count) = ("Hello", 4);
```

Answer (score 7):

If it's about dictionaries and the like, you're looking for System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>.

Answer (score 3):

I created a C# implementation of Tuples, which solves the problem generically for between two and five values - [here's the blog post](http://shadowcoding.blogspot.com/2008/12/tuples.html), which contains a link to the source.

Answer (score 3):

I typically extend the `Tuple` class into my own generic wrapper as follows:

```
public class Statistic<T> : Tuple<string, T>
{
    public Statistic(string name, T value) : base(name, value) { }
    public string Name { get { return this.Item1; } }
    public T Value { get { return this.Item2; } }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
public class StatSummary{
      public Statistic<double> NetProfit { get; set; }
      public Statistic<int> NumberOfTrades { get; set; }

      public StatSummary(double totalNetProfit, int numberOfTrades)
      {
          this.TotalNetProfit = new Statistic<double>("Total Net Profit", totalNetProfit);
          this.NumberOfTrades = new Statistic<int>("Number of Trades", numberOfTrades);
      }
}

StatSummary summary = new StatSummary(750.50, 30);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + summary.NetProfit.Name + "    Value: " + summary.NetProfit.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + summary.NumberOfTrades.Value + "    Value: " + summary.NumberOfTrades.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you might want to try out [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx).

The fact that you cannot change the key of an entry can of course be rectified by simply replacing the entire entry by a new instance of KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 2):

I was asking the same question just now after a quick google I found that There is a pair class in .NET except its in the System.Web.UI  ^ ~ ^ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx)
goodness knows why they put it there instead of the collections framework

Comment: I know about System.Web.UI.Pair. Wanted generic class though.

Comment: System.Web.UI.Pair is sealed. You cannot derive from it (in case you want to adde type safe accessors).

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 4.0 you have `System.Tuple<T1, T2>` class:

```
// pair is implicitly typed local variable (method scope)
var pair = System.Tuple.Create("Current century", 21);
```

Comment: @Alexander, you can easily look into [.NET 3.5 docs on Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(VS.90).aspx)

Comment: At the bottom they say: 
**Version Information**
*NET Framework*
Supported in: 4

Comment: @Alexander: OK, right. (Though it left me wondering why did they make this page .NET 3.5-specific)

Answer (score 1):

On order to get the above to work (I needed a pair as the key of a dictionary). I had to add:

```
    public override Boolean Equals(Object o)
    {
        Pair<T, U> that = o as Pair<T, U>;
        if (that == null)
            return false;
        else
            return this.First.Equals(that.First) && this.Second.Equals(that.Second);
    }
```

and once I did that I also added

```
    public override Int32 GetHashCode()
    {
        return First.GetHashCode() ^ Second.GetHashCode();
    }
```

to suppress a compiler warning.

Comment: You should find a better hash-code algorithm than that, try using 37+23*(h1+23*(h2+23*(h3+...))) This will make (A,B) distinct from (B,A), ie. reordering will have an effect on the code.

Comment: Comment is a accepted.. In my case I was just trying to suppress the compiler waning, and anyway T is a String and U an Int32...

Answer (score 1):

The PowerCollections library (formerly available from Wintellect but now hosted on Codeplex @ http://powercollections.codeplex.com) has a generic Pair structure.