# How can I return more than one object of different type in C# .net?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have two objects and I dont want to create a wrapper class to have data of this two object, no 'Out' parameter is there any way that I can return more than one object of different type?

Will really appreciate it!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class VPair<TFirst, TSecond>
    {
        public TFirst First { get; set; }
        public TSecond Second { get; set; }

        public VPair(TFirst first, TSecond second)
        {
            First = first;
            Second = second;
        }
    }
```

or
`Tuple` class in c#4.0

bonus:

```
public class VTriple<TFirst, TSecond, TThird> : VPair<TFirst, TSecond>
    {
        public TThird Third { get; set; }

        public VTriple(TFirst first, TSecond second, TThird third)
            : base(first, second)
        {
            Third = third;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

No. You can't.

You can use an array or a map to return them, though.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ this can be done with something called std::pair. There is a StackOverflow post on how to do it in C#: [What is C# analog of C++ std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166089/what-is-c-analog-of-c-stdpair)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a List< Object >.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new object[] { object1, object2 }
```

Alternatively, you can use an anonymous type. [See this article for more information](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx).