# How do I create a single list of object pairs from two lists in C#?

Tags: c#, list, object

I have two lists of objects. List A and List B. I need to create List C which combines List A and List B into pairs. For example:

```
List A
object a1
object a2
object a3

List B
object b1
object b2
object b3

List C (creates pairs)
object c1 (object a1, object b1)
object c2 (object a2, object b2)
object c3 (object a3, object b3)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166089/what-is-c-analog-of-c-stdpair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, U>> CombineWith<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<U> second)
{
    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool hasFirst = true;
        bool hasSecond = true;

        while (
            // Only call MoveNext if it didn't fail last time.
            (hasFirst && (hasFirst = firstEnumerator.MoveNext()))
            | // WARNING: Do NOT change to ||.
            (hasSecond && (hasSecond = secondEnumerator.MoveNext()))
            )
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(
                    hasFirst ? firstEnumerator.Current : default(T),
                    hasSecond ? secondEnumerator.Current : default(U)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I vastly prefer [Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110762/how-do-i-create-a-single-list-of-object-pairs-from-two-lists-in-c/7110781#7110781) answer.

Comment: I would use Paul's solution if I were able to use the 4.0 framework but this works on 3.5 so thanks!

Comment: @Earl How does this work on 3.5 ? `Tuple` is [only available since 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 46):

You could use the [Enumerable.Zip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method in System.Linq.

```cs
IEnumerable<ValueTuple<A, B>> pairs =
    listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => ValueTuple.Create(a, b));
```

Which can be simplified as `ValueTuple` is implied by the parentheses on the right side of the `=>`. (On the left side they enclose the lambda parameters.):

```cs
var pairs = listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => (a, b));
```

But can actually be simplified further as there is an overload that creates tuples for us:

```cs
var pairs = listA.Zip(listB);
```

Example using this resultant enumerable:

```cs
foreach (ValueTuple<A, B> pair in pairs)
{
    A a = pair.First;
    B b = pair.Second;
}
```

One could use `var` to hide the type here, but we can actually go a step further and pattern matching in the loop to bind these fields to variables:

```cs
foreach (var (a, b) in pairs)
{
    ...
}
```

---

*Before .NET 4.7 you will need to use `Tuple` instead of `ValueTuple`, specify the type explicitly and use `Item1` and `Item2` instead of `First` and `Second`.*

Comment: refer to this msdn link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Comment: So much better than my solution :).

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion - however, this appears only available in Framework 4.0. Unfortunately I'm limited to 3.5 on this project.

Comment: @Earl, in which case you will have to get the `Enumerator`s manually and iterate, as per Jonathan Dickinson's answer.

Comment: *Note in 2018 you can now do: `listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => Tuple.Create);`

Comment: *Note in 2020 you can now do: `listA.Zip(listB, ValueTuple.Create);`

Comment: Or `listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => (a,b));`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
 var listA = new object[] { "1", "2", "3" };
 var listB = new object[] { "a", "b", "c" };
 var listC = Enumerable.Zip(listA,listB, (x,y)=>new {x,y});

 foreach (var item in listC)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.x,item.y);
 }
```

Output:
   1,a
   2,b
   3,c

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core 3 has a [new overload for the Zip method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__). It takes two IEnumerables and creates one IEnumerable containing value tuples with the elements from both input IEnumerables.

```
IEnumerable<(A a, B b)> pairs = listA.Zip(listB);
```

You can use the result in multiple ways:

```
foreach((A a, B b) in pairs)
{
    // Do something with a and b
}
```

```
foreach(var (a, b) in pairs)
{
    // Do something with a and b
}
```

```
foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    A a = pair.a;
    B b = pair.b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a List of tupples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution using `System.Linq` `Enumerable.Zip` method (without specifying a function argument `Func`) would be as follows (note I've used ints to provide a simple concrete example):

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5};
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() {5,4,3,2,1};

IEnumerable<(int, int)> pairs;
pairs = list1.Zip(list2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", pairs));
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)
```