# Bit-wise AND and a normal AND

Tags: c#, .net, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Why '&&' and not '&'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not)

When would I use a *bit-wise AND* and *normal AND*?

I read the *bit-wise AND* is good for applications that have a memory limit.

Which one will be the best to use then, overall?

```
if (true & false)
{

}
```

or

```
if (true && false)
{

}
```

Wouldn't it be better to always use a *bit-wise AND* then?

Comment: "I read the a Bit-wise AND is good for applications that has a memory limit." - where have you read that? That sounds like utter nonsense to me.

Comment: `true & false` is _not_ a bitwise AND. `1 & 3` is a bitwise AND.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: How would you call the first than?

Comment: They're called full-eval and short-circuit-eval .

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It is still a bitwise AND that is happening. The full-eval thingy is only a side effect, because it needs to evaluate all operands to be able to perform the bitwise AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise AND (`&`) is a bitwise operation on both operands. `&&` instead, is a logical AND operation.

> I read the bit-wise AND is good for applications that have a memory
>   limit

This assumption is not correct. I *can* say that bitwise can be used in intensive calculus, for example in a CAD application kernel's drawing procedure when you need to divide an absolute number by 2 (say), instead of using ordinary division which is slow, we use bitwise shift `>>`. But these are extreme conditions and 99% of cases none will approve use of such techniques.

So it's basically about *performance* improvement and *not* memory.

They are completely different.