# For Loop reading infinity

Tags: android, for-loop

I am trying to make a simple screen that shows you the amount of money you have earned  by the second, so im trying to create a live feed type textveiw that updates every second with the amount of money you have earned, with my code when it runs on my phone it only reads "infinity" and when i tried to add in a 1 second delay it froze all together, here is the code that i wrote, i am using a for loop because i didnt know of a better way if anyone has a better way of achieving what i am trying to do please let me know..

```
    // Calculate pay per second
    double PPS = (HW/3600);
    double OTPPS = (OTW/3600);
    double HPDPS = (HPD*3600);
    double money = 0;
    double Reserve = 0;
    loc = 0;
    // Display
    for(int i=0; i<HPDPS & loc!=7; i++)
    {
        money = (PPS+Reserve);
        Reserve = (Reserve+money);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourpay);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(money));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

======================================================================================

Here is an edited version but i am still having a problem where it just displays infinity on the screen, how do i fix this? or how do i use the timer method?

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Receive messages from options page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    double HW = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
    double OTW = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_OTW, 0);
    double HPD = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HPD, 0);
    // Calculate pay per second
    double PPS = (HW/3600);
    double OTPPS = (OTW/3600);
    double HPDPS = (HPD*3600);
    double money = 0;
    double Reserve = 0;
    // Display
    for(int i=0; i<HPDPS; i++)
    {
        money = (PPS+Reserve);
        Reserve = (Reserve+money);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourpay);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(money));
    }


    // set textView

}
```

Comment: You have a & in the loop condition where I guess you wanted && ?

Comment: double PPS = (HW/3600); I don't see an initialization for HW

Comment: Use TimerTask as suggested by Arun.  Whatever you do don't do a Thread.sleep() on the UI thread

Comment: @Michael It happens that `&` works too in this case, but you are probably right.

Comment: @ Jyro117 @CSmith This is in my .java file and HW is declared above the code the piece of code i pasted on here and i changed it to && and im still having the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to user a `Timer` and `TimerTask`.

EDIT:
 Here is a sample application code to user Timer and TimerTask:

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final Timer t =new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    t1.setText("Hello" + counter++); //Place your text data here

                    //Place your stopping condition over here. Its important to have a stopping condition or it will go in an infinite loop. 
                    if(counter == 10)
                        t.cancel(); 
                }
            }); 
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how would i go about doing this? ive never used the timertask or timer

Comment: I always test the code before pasting it as a solution. This sample code is also tested and its working. Maybe the way you declared the `counter` variable is wrong. Declare `counter` as a `global` variable and it will increment from 0-9 at an interval of 1 second.

Comment: sorry for the late response but i was out of town for the weekend, i am about to test this but it keeps telling me that i dont need the first @overide? its gives me an error on run() until i remove it.... could i be putting this code in the wrong place? i am putting it inside a "public void sendMessage(View view) {}" on my activty.java file

Answer (score -1):

[1] You are doing **Bitwise ANDing** (Bitwise ANDing -> &) here

```
for(int i=0; i<HPDPS & loc!=7; i++)
                     ^
```

[2] Your loc in always 0, because you did **loc=0** and in for loop loc is never updated

So loc!=7 is **ALWAYS TRUE**

Comment: Your [1] is wrong: `&` is also a boolean operator. It is a bitwise operator when used between numbers, but here the `<` and `!=` have higher precendence so the expression is equivalent to `(i<HPDPS) & (loc!=7)` and returns the same value as `(i<HPDPS) && (loc!=7)`.

Comment: See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411907/what-are-the-cases-in-which-it-is-better-to-use-unconditional-and-instead-of/11412037#11412037).

Comment: No @assylias, **&** is Bitwise ANDing, && is Operator for condition.

Comment: loc is declared before the for loop and gets set to 7 when my stop button is pressed

Comment: What Nonse... @assylias, it is Bitwise ANDing. Try it as following:  int i = 1;
     if (i == 0 & ++i != 2) {
      System.out.println("i"+i);
     }
     System.out.println(i); //2
     i = 1;
     if (i == 0 && ++i != 2) {
      System.out.println("i"+i);
     }
     System.out.println(i); //1

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani Whatever you call it, I'm saying that `(i<HPDPS) & (loc!=7)` and `(i<HPDPS) && (loc!=7)` will always return the same result.