# Why are there 2 boolean type operators in Java?

Tags: java, boolean-operations

As said in thinking in Java if you have 2 boolean objects, `x` and `y` you can use either `x= x&&y` and `x=x&y` on them, so why its necessary having both types?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411907/what-are-the-cases-in-which-it-is-better-to-use-unconditional-and-instead-of

Answer (score 12):

The two operators act differently:

- `&` will always evaluate *both* operands
- `&&` is *short-circuiting* - if the first operand evaluates to `false`, then the overall result will always be false, and the second operand isn't evaluated

See the Java Language Specification for more details:

- [Section 15.22 (Boolean Logical Operators) for `&`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)
- [Section 15.23 (Conditional-And Operator) for `&&`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23)

Comment: +1, also, the short-circuiting form is almost always what you will want to use.  It's especially useful for avoiding NPEs, like: `if (someVar != null && someVar.getSomeProp() == 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the output of this code:

```
    int x = 0;
    boolean b = false & (++x == 1); // b is false
    System.out.println(x); // prints 1
    x = 0;
    b = false && (++x == 1); // b is false
    System.out.println(x); // prints 0
```

It's different because `&` will always evaluate both operands, whereas `&&` won't look at the second operand if the first one is `false` because the whole expression will always be `false` no matter what the second operand is.

Answer (score 2):

1. `&` will evaluate both the operands
2. `&&` will skip evaluation of the second operand if the first operand is false

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR I'm tempted.

Answer (score 1):

& is a bitwise 'and' operator, && is a boolean 'and'

& will always evaluate both the left and right sides, && will only evaluate the left if that is sufficient to evaluate the expression (e.g. false && true : only the LHS is evaluated because if the LHS is false, the whole expression must be false)