# Strange implementation of Guava LongMath.checkedAdd

Tags: java, guava, long-integer, integer-overflow

```
public static long checkedAdd(long a, long b) {
    long result = a + b;
    checkNoOverflow((a ^ b) < 0 | (a ^ result) >= 0);
    return result;
}
```

I am interested why boolean logical | is used here. Why not to use conditional short circuited ||?

Comment: How would you have written it?

Comment: checkNoOverflow((a ^ b) < 0 || (a ^ result) >= 0);

Comment: Not that uncommon in code that wants to avoid branching for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment in that class:

```
// NOTE: Whenever both tests are cheap and functional, it's faster to use 
// &, | instead of &&, ||
```

More context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412121/869736