# Does the logical AND operator have any use here?

Tags: java

I have been reading through the source code of an API implementation I use and stumbled upon this part of the code:

```
if (condition1 & condition2 && (condition3 || condition4))
```

Conditions 1 and 2 do not call any methods or perform any actions, while 3 and 4 do. I am wondering why the programmer decided not to use the short-circuit && operator for comparing the first two statements as I cannot see any benefit in using it (one more condition to check, the other two conditions which could actually have any influence on other parts of the program are still short-circuit).

Comment: @arshajii I was thinking the same, but in Java the operands of `&&` and the expression inside an `if` _must_ be `boolean`

Comment: @Alnitak Yea, you're right. I just realized that.

Comment: Well, if conditions 1 and 2 are simple Boolean variables the `&` is faster and works just as well.  Or if they are expressions that are almost certainly true (and the validity of the second doesn't depend on the truth of the first) it works just as well.

Comment: @arshajii yep, both booleans, the first is a flag and the second is an object identity comparison

Comment: @HotLicks shouldn't the `&&` be slightly faster because the second condition doesn't need to be checked if the first is `false`?

Comment: It takes time to do a conditional branch.  ANDing together too Boolean values is incredibly cheap.

Comment: (However, using "two" instead of "too", where appropriate, seems to be rather difficult for me at times.)

Comment: The programmer made a typo, that's all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the cases in which it is better to use unconditional AND (& instead of &&)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411907/what-are-the-cases-in-which-it-is-better-to-use-unconditional-and-instead-of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason for doing this that I can think of would be to avoid the branch that is coupled with `&&`. You can see this in the bytecode:

`a & b`:

```
ILOAD 1
ILOAD 2
IAND
```

`a && b`:

```
ILOAD 1
IFEQ L3
ILOAD 2
IFEQ L3
ICONST_1
GOTO L4
```

It's certainly possible that there are cases where `&` marginally outperforms `&&` as a result (specifically, when you're almost certain that the first condition will be true). Nevertheless, `&&` is generally preferred because 1) such cases are rare and 2) the performance difference, in most contexts, would be completely negligible.

Comment: Does this apply if you have an identity comparison check in the second condition? I would think that that might be a bit slower.

Comment: @yawkat It could apply if you're almost certain that the first condition will be `true`. In any case, it's very difficult to tell without timing it yourself.

Comment: The "framework" will be essentially the same regardless.  Where there is conditional logic in the second condition it could work out that the two would be equally fast, but I have difficulty thinking of any scenario where the second would be faster (given that the first condition is true).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how often `condition1` is true, it would have been better (very slightly more efficient) to use `&&`, because the second operand `condition2` doesn't need to be checked if `condition1` is false, which may save a couple of CPU instructions.

If statistically `condition1` is true more often than not, it's probably more efficient to use `&`, because the (usually unnecessary) short circuit check would be skipped.

In java you're allowed to use the bitwise and `&` with boolean operands to give a boolean result, but
the only time there's a functional difference between using `&` and `&&` is if code is called in the second operand, eg:

```
condition1 & <some code giving a boolean> // exdcutes "some code" regardless of condition1
condition1 && <some code giving a boolean> // only executes "some code" if condition1 is true
```

I would consider using `&` to always run `<some code giving a boolean>` to be in "side effect" territory, and not worth the confusion it would cause.

Comment: Bohemian, I observe that @Hot Licks (@HotLicks?) wrote in a comment above that `&` is faster than `&&`. Here you're saying the reverse. Perhaps someone disagrees. Or supported your point.  Personally I think your answer is correct in this case.

Comment: "There is no benefit".  From Arshajii's answer it's clear that `&` is faster.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but "the only time there's a difference" could be reworded "the only time there's a different behaviour". The behaviour is the same otherwise, even if there can be marginal time advantages.

Comment: @weston yeah fair call - now says " a functional difference".

Comment: @HotLicks It's only faster if `condition1` is true.

Comment: There can be a functional difference if the second condition has any potential side-effect (eg, exception), whether it calls something or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually one reason that the & operator could have been desired over &&, taking into account the point already discussed about & being just as fast if the conditions are boolean.

In the Java language specification, §15.7.

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.
>
> It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification.
>   Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side
>   effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on
>   exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right
>   evaluation of expressions.

If you check the [order of operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), you will see that & comes before &&. Thus, this statement sticks to the principle of being clear about the order of evaluation without depending on Java evaluating left to right. This choice would be especially important if condition3 or condition4 call modifying methods - although this would be bad coding.

Comment: If the author of the code was truly concerned about this he could just include another set of parenthesis `(condition1 && condition2)`.

Comment: If `&&` were used the conditions would still be evaluated in the same order, since `&&` is *always* evaluated left-to-right.  The only situation where there could be a detectable difference is if the second condition has a side-effect that one wants to always occur, even if the first condition is false.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, since `&&` for sure forces left-right evaluation. Then again, is that really any more clear to the reader that it will evalute left to right? It's details of OoO vs details of short-circuiting. I'm not trying to say that what the author did is what everyone should do. `&&` is almost definitely better.

Comment: I think we all can agree that if there were any functional reasons (vs "personal preference" or minor performance reasons) for the choice, the programmer should have included a comment explaining that.

Comment: @HotLicks I can definitely agree to that. Guess I just like playing Devil's Advocate. :)