# In C#, which `if` statement is faster?

Tags: c#, performance, bit-manipulation

Which `if` statement is faster, with the following conditions. It seems the short-circuit will compile into more instructions then the non-short-circuit.

```
bool force = false;
bool _isLoadingActual = true;
bool _isLoadingLoadCore = true;

int a = 0, b = 0;

if (force | !(_isLoadingActual | _isLoadingLoadCore))
{
    a = 1;
}

if (force || !(_isLoadingActual || _isLoadingLoadCore))
{
    b = 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: @AMissico If you ran the code you wouldn't have any questions.

Comment: @AMissico by measuring the time to do it 1000s of times.

Comment: @AMissico How do you think that anyone knows which one is faster? You have to compare the execution times.

Comment: @AMissico If you had said that in the first place, no one would have commented asking why you didn't run it.

Comment: [obligatory link to performance rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @AMissico There are lots and lots of things you can spend your time on that are likely to actually be helpful.  If this is honestly the most interesting thing you could inquire about you're not trying very hard to find interesting topics.

Comment: @AMissico The spirit of StackOverflow is not to do things you can't be bothered doing, it's about finding solutions to problems you can't find yourself.

Comment: @AMissico If it would take you hours of digging to find the MSDN docs for the operators you're using, maybe you shouldn't be worrying about micro-optimizations yet.

Comment: @AMissico No, just making an observation.  Either you're vastly overstating the amount of time it would have taken you to find the information Alexi posted, or you literally shouldn't be worrying about micro-optimizations.  I don't mean that as an insult, I mean that as advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24866/discussion-between-theevilpenguin-and-amissico)

Comment: You may also want to read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not/7331721#7331721) to a more general question about these operators to understand their differences. In the same question, another user posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7331897/572644) that talks specifically about the differences in performance.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, +1, Awesome. Perfect. I disassembled the code (see comment on Alexei Levenkov answer) and was going to bench test it today if I had a chance. Can convert your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @AMissico: This question has already been closed, no more answers are allowed. Unfortunatelly, it has been closed as "too localized". I actually voted to close it as a duplicate to the question I linked to. I think that topic has been discussed in every possible detail in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fastest solution

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
```

Since you already know the boolean variables value.

No seriously.. The 2nd one is probably faster because it can short-circuit, that is if you did not hard code the first boolean to false! Otherwise, short circuiting seems like it must be faster.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `a` & `b` will equal `0`...

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I realized the if-statements evaluate to false, but I mixed up the value he assigned.. sorta beside the point... but thanks I need to fix that

Comment: hehe, no probs. I thought I was going crazy for a second

Answer (score 0):

I think the faster is the second code.

```
if (force || !(_isLoadingActual || _isLoadingLoadCore))
{
    b = 1;
}
```

Because it's a [Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In above code, if `force` is true then the rest condition (`!(_isLoadingActual || _isLoadingLoadCore)`) not need to be checked.

Comment: What about the conditional if, the compiler would have to generate for the short-circuit?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7331897/572644) for more info on "branch mis-prediction". Bottom line: If all three of those operands are already boolean values (and not methods that return booleans), the short circuiting evaluation is *slower*, because there are multiple branches (`if(force) {} else { if (...) ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "which one of the `|` or `||` does short circuit":

- `||` does short circuit - [|| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346.aspx)

  > If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to true or false.
- `|` does not short circuit - [| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kxszd0kx.aspx)

  > For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

So in pure theoretical sense code with `||` would be faster, also most likely you will not be able to measure impact of the difference in real code.

Note that two statements are not equivalent if computation of operands have side effects (not your case as you have bool variables already).

Comment: >>Assuming your question is "which one of the | or || does short circuit": << No. I have the bitwise operator on purpose. It seems performing the bitwise operation then the conditional would be faster than performing all the conditionals.

Comment: When used on two bools, `|` is not a bitwise operator, it's a non-short circuting boolean operator.

Comment: @AMissico, there is no "bitwise or" defined for bool type in C# - check the link (also I've inlined main part) - it is not "bitwise OR" for `bool`, but rather "non-short-curcuit OR".

Comment: Isn't logical OR the same as bitwise for boolean values?

Comment: @AMissico, to the extent yes - assuming single bit values. But since it is not explicitly defined as "bitwise" compiler/JIT are free to use the same code as regular "OR" if find necessary. So the only real difference between your 2 statements is if second "OR" need to evaluate right argument for result.

Comment: Interesting, the IL has a few `brtrue` and `br` statements. It also looks like bitwise `or` is being used in the first `if` statement. Therefore, the bool must be converted to integer values before the bitwise operation. Now I am really interested in testing performance.

Comment: Question, `or` "Computes the bitwise OR of two integer values, returns an integer." This means the bitwise OR is explicit because we are in IL and out of C#. Correct?