# What is the meaning of the ?. and ?? operators

Tags: c#

The code is as follows:

```
if(f1) 
{ 
    return a1?.a2 ?? a3 
}
```

Can anyone tell the use of these operators here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why && and not &](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not)

Comment: return a1?.a2 ?? a3

a1 can be null. If it isnt, then it will return a2. If both are null, then a3 is returned.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: [Null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and [Null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: `?`= null-conditional operator, `??`= null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @TheNoob: `?.` binds tighter than `??`, so if `a1` is non-null but `a1.a2` is null, `a1?.a2 ?? a3` will return `a3`. And note that there isn't just an "a2" - there's "a1.a2`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was trying to explain that but you did it better. xP And omg Jon Skeet replied to me =O You helped me way too many times from your answers on SO. Heres my shot to say Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2):

first the operator ?? example:

```
var c = a ?? b;
```

is equivalent to

```
var c = a == null ? b : a;
```

the second one ?. it is to not throw NullReferenceException example:

```
var c = a?.Name;
```

is equivalent to

```
var c = a == null ? null : a.Name;
```

it is short cuts to avoid ifs and long lines

Did you get it ?

Comment: One important thing to note on primitive types at the end of a long ?. is that they are all turned into Nullable Types.  Which means you can't compare directly with certain values.  You may have to use .GetValueOrDefault(), or some of the other Nullable functions.