# In C, is single & and single | valid so as to avoid short circuit? Also please give some examples of utility of same in C#

Tags: c#, c, short-circuiting

`&&` is logical AND and `||` is Logical OR

In C#, for example,

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(num>=0&&num<=10)
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now for `&&` only if both the conditions are true, then the `if` block gets executed, else `else` block gets executed.

So for input `2` conditions `num>=0` and `num<=10` are both `true`. So condition `num>=0&&num<=10` is `true` and `if` statement gets executed. get output `Hi`.

For input `-2` condition `num<=10` is `true` but condition `num>=0` is `false`. Since both the conditions should be true, condition `num>=0 && num<=10` is false so instead of `for` statement `else` statement gets executed. So the output is `Hello`.

For input `12` condition `num>=0` is `true` but condition `num<=10` is `false`. Since both the conditions should be true, condition `num>=0 && num<=10` is false so instead of `for` statement `else` statement gets executed. So the output is `Hello`.

Now, in this case if the first condition `num>=0` comes out to be `flase` compiler does not check the second condition `num<=10`, since in case of `&&` if both the conditions are `true`, only then `num>=0&&num<=10` is `true`.

Now consider the following program -

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(num>=0&num<=10)
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here instead of `&&`, `&` is given

The output will be same as the truth table for `&&` and `&` are same.

But here, during evaluation of the condition `num>=0&num=<10`, if the input is `-2`, then first condition `num>=0` is `false`. But unlike `&&` even after first condition is `false` second condition `num<=10` is evaluated, and then the control passes on to the next statement.

---

Similarly for logical OR; consider the following C# example -

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(num<=0||num>=10)
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

If input is `-2`, first condition `num<=0` is `true` and second condition `num>=10` is `false`. Since in `||` `num<=0||num>=10` is `true` if either of the two statements are `true`, so `if` block gets executed and the ouput is `Hi`.

If input is `12` first condition `num<=0` is `false` but second condition `num>=10` is `true`. For `||` `num<=0||num>=10` is `true` if either condition is `true`, so `if` block gets executed and the output is `Hi`.

If input is `2` first condition `num<=0` is `false`. Also second condition `num>=10` is false. Since both the conditions are `false` `num<=0||num>=10` is `flase` and `else` block gets executed. So output is `Hello`.

Now consider the following program -

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(num<=0|num>=10)
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here instead of `||` `|` is used. Both the programs generate same output as truth tables of `||` and `|` are same.

But when `||` is used and if input is `-2`, first condition `num<=0` is `true`. Since for `num<=0||num>=10` to be `true` either conditions needs to be `true` and first condition `num<=0` is already true, compiler doesn't check the second condition `num>=10`

But when `|` is used and here also the input is `-2`, even after evaluating the first condition `num<=0` to be true, compiler checks the second condition `num>=10`

---

#### Concept of ""Short Circuit" in C

Let us consider the following example -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    a = -1;
    b = 0;
    c = ++a && ++b;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
a = 0, b = 1, c = 0
```

Real output:

```
a = 0, b = 0, c = 0
```

It is because in the statement `c = ++a && ++b;` when the value of `a` is incremented by `1` it's new value is `0`. `0` is evaluated to be `false`. In `&&` the whole condition is `false` if either the first condition or second condition is `false`.  So here as `++a` is evaluated to be `false` the condition `++b` is never checked by the compiler. So `b` is never incremented and its value stays `0`

Now consider the following example -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    a = 0;
    b = 10;
    c = ++a || ++b;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
a = 1, b = 11, c = 1
```

Real output:

```
a = 1, b = 10, c = 1
```

Here in the statement

```
c = ++a || ++b;
```

`++a` is `1` and `1` is evaluated as `true`. In `||` the whole condition is `true` if either the first condition or second condition is `true`. Here since first condition `++a` is true, second condition `++b` is never checked by the compiler. So the value of `b` is never incremented and stays `10`.

---

Now, my question -

1. Is `&` and `|` valid in C so that short circuit can be avoided?
2. In C# `bool` can only be `true`, `false` or `null`. Unlike C `0` is not `false` and all `non-zero` value is not `true`. 
   So short circuit can never take place in C#. So in C# what is the utility of `&` and `|`?

Comment: OMG that's a lot of text. Why would you ever want to "avoid" short-circuiting? It's a *good* thing to have!

Comment: You really don't have to explain how C# works to the veteran C# programmers here, I think they are quite aware.

Comment: Short-circuiting in C# is definitely a thing that is both useful and works fine, try evaluating methods in the two branches.

Comment: In C, `|` and `&` are *bit-wise* operators, whereas `||` and `&&` are *logical* operators. This is different from C#.

Comment: Answer: in C, the `|` and `&` have unspecified order of evaluation. They do not "short-circuit". But they also don't mean the same thing as `||` and `&&`, because they are bit-wise versus logical operators.

Comment: IMO this question is more than twice as long as it actually needs to be.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen How is this different from C#? They are bitwise and logical operators there as well.

Comment: In C, `|` is a bitwise operator. In C#, `|` is a bitwise operator if applied to integers, logical if applied to bools. Same difference for `&`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Right. I even wrote that once in an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331721/572644

Comment: There have been multiple rather lively discussions in comment threads on Stack Overflow about how `|` and `||` differ and what they can be used for so contrary to what @Lundin said, not *all* C# programmers know about this.

Comment: When int cannot be evaluated is bool in C# and hence logical operations can't be performed, why & and | is present? And if present to avoid short circuit, how short circuit can occur?

Comment: `if (a() && b())` is different from `if (a() & b())`. If `a()` returns `false`, `b()` will not be called and evaluated in the first example, but will be called and evaluated in the second.

Comment: And so you are saying that in C also & and I can be used and as a result short circuit can be avoided?

Comment: No, in C `&` and `|` are **bitwise** operators, they don't deal with logical results at all, hence talking about short-circuit boolean evaluation here is irrelevant.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I only said "veteran C# programmers", not the rest of them :) Preferably one of the former should answer this question. Me, I only got lured here by the C tag.

Comment: "Basically, the purpose of the &, | and ^ operators is not to do logical tests in C, its just that the language is type-unsafe enough to allow this as a side-effect." as said by @AdamBrown, so let be as a side effect, it is do functioning in C?

Comment: [sigh] just code so that it does not matter...

Comment: This comment thread serves no use right now. Read up on the documentation for both C and C# and you will find everything is pretty well documented.

Comment: @puregeek often the purpose of &, | and ^ operators in C is to do up to 64 logical tests in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions:

> Is & and | valid in C so that short circuit can be avoided?

No. The `&` and `|` operators in C mean different things compared to their C# logical counterparts.

In C, `&` and `|` are bitwise operators. They will evaluate both the sides and combine the *bits* of the resulting values according to the operator. Afterwards, if the resulting value is used in a *logical* context it will be processed as 0=false, everything else=true.

This is **not** the same as short-circuit logical operators as C# have.

> In C# bool can only be true, false or null. Unlike C 0 is not false and all non-zero value is not true. So short circuit can never take place in C#.
>
> So in C# what is the utility of & and |?

The purpose of `&` and `|` as logical operators in C# is to support non-short-circuit evaluation.

Take this example:

```
// s is string
if (s != null && s.Length > 0) { ... }
```

Here, if `s` is indeed `null`, the value of the first operand is `false`, hence the whole expression can never be `true` and thus the second operand, `s.Length > 0` is **not** evaluated.

Contrast to this:

```
if (s != null & s.Length > 0) { ... }
```

Observe that I switched to the non-short-circuit `&` operator here. Here, if `s` is null, **both** operands will still be evaluated and the code will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

In some situations, it may be beneficial and required that you evaluate both sides **even if** you know the result will never be false regardless of what the second operand says. In those situations, you would use the non-short-circuit operators.

---

In C, the operators mean this:

- `|` = bitwise OR operator
- `&` = bitwise AND operator
- `||` = logical OR operator that short circuits
- `&&` = logical AND operator that short circuits

In C#, the operators mean this:

- `|` = bitwise OR operator **if applied to integers, logical non-short-circuit OR operator if applied to bools**
- `&` = bitwise AND operator **if applied to integers, logical non-short-circuit AND operator if applied to bools**
- `||` = logical OR operator that short circuits
- `&&` = logical AND operator that short circuits

Answer (score 1):

The single-character operators `&` and `|` are *bitwise* AND and OR, respecitvely. They have nothing to do with boolean tests, for which the short-circuiting `&&` and `||` are used.

I don't quite see the point of your questions:

1. They are "valid", they are C operators, but their use is not for boolean logic, they are for computing binary results.
2. In C# they seem to serve dual purposes, described as "Integer bitwise AND, Boolean logical AND" in [the operators documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/operators#operators-evaluation-and-operator-precedence). But I don't use C#.

Comment: In C# `|` and `&` are non-short-circuit boolean operators **and** bitwise operators (just as they are in C), so these operators have dual meaning depending on the types involved. That is, to clarify, if the operators are used on integers they're bitwise, if they're used on bools they're logical.

Answer (score 0):

& and | are not logical operators. Using them as logical operators takes advantage of the C language feature that zero is false and non-zero is true (which is not fully type safe).

C# is a fully type safe language, so logical expressions must be boolean. This means that logical operators will only work on booleans (&&, ||) whereas bitwise operations only work on integral types (&, |, ^)

Basically, the purpose of the &, | and ^ operators is not to do logical tests in C, its just that the language is type-unsafe enough to allow this as a side-effect.

EDIT: I stand corrected, (&, |) are also apparently valid logical operators in C# (just shorthand for &&, ||)

Comment: Though in C# both `&` and `|` are also logical operators, non-short-circuit logical operators, if applied to bools. They're bitwise if applied to integers.

Comment: `|` and `&` are not short-hand for `||` and `&&` respectively. If you know C, stick to answering for C :) `|` and `||` mean different things. The same underlying operation, logical OR, but the exact behavior is different so you can't save a character in your code by omitting one of those characters and keep the current behavior. As such they're not short-hand.

Comment: C does allow `& | ^ ~` for boolean operands, because how else would you set the bit(s) of a boolean? :) As it turns out, C will actually implicitly promote the bool operands to `signed int`. So that code like `~false` actually gives you a negative result. Happy days.