# How do i add info from 2 different arrays to a file?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, save

i have two arrays of the same length that i would like to use the contents. index[0] of both array a and b should be used together when i am saving to a json file.i am guessing i need to lopp thru them in order to access each index and save the contents to a template json every time. i also would like that it returns a toString() format of the json, so each iteration for each index returns  something.

```
 public string Show(string[] id, string[] msg)
   {
   // opening code for json file with jobject and jsontexreader
   for (int i = 0; i <= id.Length; i++ )
      {                    
                Newid = id[i];
                Newmsg = msgs[i];
                // setting the data to the json file
                JObject temp = (JObject)o1.SelectToken(path1);
                temp["data"] = msg;
                JObject tem = (JObject)o1.SelectToken(path2);
                tem["ksid"] = id;

        }
       return ??;
```

}

Comment: What's your actual question? This is just a list of requirements.

Comment: Is there any chance that the `msg` length will be different from the length of `id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a single list of object pairs from two lists in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110762/how-do-i-create-a-single-list-of-object-pairs-from-two-lists-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of accomplishing what you wanted to do

```
string Show(string[] id, string[] msg)
{
    if (id.Length != msg.Length) 
        throw new Exception(nameof(id) + " is not the same length as " + nameof(msg));

    List<object> data = new List<object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
    {
        data.Add(new
        {
            Ksid = id[i],
            Data = msg[i]
        });
    }

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

Comment: how would i be able to add the Ksid and Data into a json file template? say i have a json file of  the following that i will put the data and id inside. then after ti copies this json format i want to output the json with th enew info added { 
 "messageR": {
 "appId": "myApp",
 
   "messages": {
     "message": {
       "content": {
  "priorityService": "false",
  "data": "Test Message",
  "mimeType": "text/plain"
        },
      }
     }

   }

}

Comment: yes i tried it, i had to tweak some other things around but thank you.