# How to combine two arrays with identical index I make a list?

Tags: c#

Input (pseudocode):

```
var array1=[1,2,3,4];
var array2=[5,6,7,8];
```

Result (pseudocode):

```
var output={[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a single list of object pairs from two lists in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110762/how-do-i-create-a-single-list-of-object-pairs-from-two-lists-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
var output = array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => new [] { a, b });
```

If you need it as a `List<int>` or `int[]`, you can materialise it with `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` respectively.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/SGHP54287)

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is to use linq `Select` EX:

```
int [] array1 =new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int [] array2 = new[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var array3 = array1.Select((x, index) => new int[] { x, array2[index] }).ToArray();
```