# When/How to replace a for loop with foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I am creating an integer set class where the object can hold up to 101 numbers through a boolean array. My assignment is to use foreach loops whenever possible, but I can't quite find a place where I can use it / where it would even make sense to use it.

Here are some snippets of my code, and I did the program exactly as my teacher asked. I can't quite figure out union set into a foreach loop if it is even possible. Can this program be improved by a foreach loop, and if so, where?

```
public bool[] set = new bool[101];

public IntegerSet(){

    for (int k = 0; k < set.Length; k++)
    {
        set[k] = false;
    }

public IntegerSet unionSet  (IntegerSet a)
{
    IntegerSet c = new IntegerSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)

    {
        if (a.set[i] == true || this.set[i] == true)
            c.set[i] = true;
    }

    return c;
}

public bool isEqual(IntegerSet a)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (a.set[i] == this.set[i])
            count++;
    }
    if (count == 101)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `public bool[] set = new bool[101];`

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your isEqual method could be made more efficient. No need to count the number of good matches -- return false as soon as you find a wrong match.

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't holding integers,t hat is the way my teacher wanted me to implement it. Thanks for the advice for the isEqual algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you use a `foreach` loop in situations when you process a single collection *without modifying it*. In situations when you have multiple collections, a loop with an index is more appropriate.

In your case, none of the three loops fits the description above:

- The first loop writes to the array
- The second and third loops process multiple sequences.

You can simplify your code quite a bit, but whenever you use two sets, a `for` loop is more appropriate (I assume that using LINQ is not an option).

```
public IntegerSet unionSet  (IntegerSet other) {
    IntegerSet res = new IntegerSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        res.set[i] = other.set[i] || this.set[i];
    return res;
}
public bool isEqual(IntegerSet a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    if (a.set[i] != this.set[i])
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Just to be complete, with LINQ in place you can avoid most loops:

```
public IntegerSet unionSet(IntegerSet other) {
    // Assume that you have a constructor that takes IEnumerable<bool>
    new IntegerSet(set.Zip(other.set, (a, b) => a || b));
}
public bool isEqual(IntegerSet a) {
    return set.SequenceEqual(a.set);
}
```

Comment: dunno whats up with the downvotes round here. Your post is spot on.

Comment: Excellent answer, that was exactly what I was looking for: whether we can modify the collection as well.

Comment: Bonus for the LINQ awesomeness!

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule of thumb that might help you:

> Use for loops for arrays and foreach loops for iterators

All of your collections seem to be arrays so your loop usage (fors) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First for loop can't be replaced with foreach because it is not possible to change elements in foreach loop.

Second and third for loop are not very good candidates because foreach loops traverses through one set, but you need them to traverse through both sets.

You could in theory use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx) (available from .NET 4) or create a function that returns `IEnumerable<Pair<int,int>>`, where `Pair` is a class that just [holds two values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166094/395718), and then use this function in both `unionSet` and `isEqual`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955766/395718) for example, with `KeyValuePair` standing for imagined `Pair`. This could be what teacher is asking for, or it could be an overkill. Depends on the teacher.

Comment: Your answer is actually really good, but I find the first sentece misleading... I bet my house I can replace first *for* with *foreach*.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace each of these for loops with this construction:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(bool b in set)
{
   set[counter] = true;
   counter++;
}
```

Also, mind that any `bool[] table = new bool[10];` has all values set to `false`, as the `false` is default value for bool type.

Comment: It's true it could be replaced, but it wouldn't be improvement. Also that foreach looks kind of silly :D

Comment: I think it is silly altogether how my teacher wants me to do this when it just seems out of place.

Comment: @krikara well I think you have a good teacher... it's good to know the difference between *for* and *foreach*

Comment: Yeah but the grading rubrick says -5 points if I don't use foreach. And it just seems so unnatural here.

Comment: @krikara Yes... it can be done with foreach... but you can be smarter and add comments where you explain why it's not good to use the foreach there :) I am sure it was just supposed to show why you really wouldn't use the foreach...